# Astyanax / Cassandra InstantiationException when reading column / columnlist (Scala)

Tags: scala, cassandra, astyanax

Stuck for hours on this one!  Thanks so much for any insight :)

- Scala 2.9.2
- Astyanax 1.0.6 (also tried 1.0.5)
- Cassandra 1.1.4
- Using CompositeRowKey, CompositeColumnName
- No problem inserting into Cassandra
- Can read a row, ColumnList.size() returns correct count however any attempt to access ColumnList (i.e. iterate, access iterate ColumnList, getColumnByIndex(), getColumnByName(), etc) will throw the following exception:

Exception:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException

relevant stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException: shops.integration.db.scalaquery.ReportingDao$MetricsLogFileCompositeColumn
        at com.netflix.astyanax.serializers.AnnotatedCompositeSerializer.fromByteBuffer(AnnotatedCompositeSerializer.java:136)
        at com.netflix.astyanax.serializers.AbstractSerializer.fromBytes(AbstractSerializer.java:40)
        at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.model.ThriftColumnOrSuperColumnListImpl.constructMap(ThriftColumnOrSuperColumnListImpl.java:201)
        at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.model.ThriftColumnOrSuperColumnListImpl.getColumn(ThriftColumnOrSuperColumnListImpl.java:189)
        at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.model.ThriftColumnOrSuperColumnListImpl.getColumnByName(ThriftColumnOrSuperColumnListImpl.java:103)
```

Specifically:

```
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
at com.netflix.astyanax.serializers.AnnotatedCompositeSerializer.createContents(AnnotatedCompositeSerializer.java:167)
```

Relevant sample code:

```
class TestCompositeColumn(@(Component @field) var logFileId: Long, @(Component @field) var dt: String, @(Component @field) var dk: String) extends Ordered[TestCompositeColumn] {
    def this() = this(0l, "", "")
    //equals, hashCode, compare all implemented
}
```

I've also tried this variation on the class:

```
class TestCompositeColumn(idIn: Long, key1In: String, key2In: String) extends Ordered[TestCompositeColumn] {
    @Component(ordinal = 0) var id: Long = idIn
    @Component(ordinal = 1) var key1: String = key1In
    @Component(ordinal = 2) var key2: String = key2In

    def this() = this(0, null, null)
    //equals, hashCode, compare all implemented
}
```

---

```
val TEST_COLUMN_FAMILY = new ColumnFamily[TestRowKey, TestCompositeColumn](
    "test_column_family",
    new AnnotatedCompositeSerializer[TestRowKey](classOf[TestRowKey]),
    new AnnotatedCompositeSerializer[TestCompositeColumn](classOf[TestCompositeColumn]),
    BytesArraySerializer.get());

var columnList = keyspace.prepareQuery(TEST_COLUMN_FAMILY)
    .getKey(TestRowKey(1l, 2012090100))
    .execute().getResult()

    // OK - will return 6 for example, also verified via cassandra-cli
    println(columnList.size())         

    // ERROR - will throw exception above.  Iterating, or any type of access will also throw same exception
    println(columnList.getColumnByIndex(0).getStringValue())
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that TestCompositeColumn cannot be defined as an inner class.